# How to stop Application Pool on server when doing a Visual Studio 2017 .net core IIS publish?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.net Core Web Application and I am struggling to do a one-click publish from Visual Studio 2017 to an IIS server on the network.

On the server, the website is running already. The issue is when there is a need to publish a new version of the website from Visual Studio.

Right now I do this manually and would like a one-click solution so that I (and others on my team) don't have to manually stop the app pool, publish, and start app pool.

I have created my publish profile to go to File System \\[server]\wwwroot[MySite] but I cannot replace it without stopping the Application Pool. How do I tell Visual Studio to Stop the App pool, publish, then start the App pool?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9658849/1531971

Comment: Why are you publishing from local machine instead of build server?