# Calling WebApi immediately after updating the IIS server, returning the error message "A task was canceled"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

Calling WebApi immediately after updating the IIS server, returning the error message "A task was canceled". But after the release, wait for a while to call the interface and this problem will never happen. I don't know if it was just released, IIS is not loaded yet? What does IIS work like after updating files?

The project target framework is .NET framework 4.5.

Comment: IIS recycles the application pool and reloads your updated dlls and caches some items before the app gets ready. It may be quick or take a while, depends on your application and required resources. More details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658924/2174170)

Comment: How did you update your IIS server? You mean update your IIS release version or install windows update. What error message did you see in event viewer application log?

Comment: Thanks for you help, this is what I want to know. My English is not good and I am newer to stackoverflow, I am sorry for the trouble with you. I mean upgrading my project to the IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding,  When you update your project for your IIS website, Application pool will be recycled and your application need some time to pre-complied Again.

When you access the web service during the pre-compile process. Your application pool pipeline would probably cancel the task. That's why you will no longer receive this error after a while.  As long as you don't receive "task canceled" error any more, you don't have to worry about that.